# Difference between kernel source and root

Tags: linux-kernel, root

This a certainly a dumb question, but when I look at the sources of the linux kernel of raspberry pi (here : https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux), this is not the same as the root organisation (that you can find here : http://labor-liber.org/en/gnu-linux/introduction/tree). However, there are some similarities (ex : usr repository).

Do someone know why?

Thank you!

Comment: What you mean by "both  are not same"?.  Both will be different.

First link contains the kernel source code  while second link contains the filesystem of the OS.

Answer (score 0):

**Kernel sources** are files for build the kernel. Usually, these files are located *in some directory*. After building (and installing) sources can be safetly cleaned.

**Root directory** is the *top-level* directory for *working OS*.

Most of subdirectory names common between between kernel sources and root directory are just accidental coincidence.

Answer (score 0):

First link only contains the **kernel source code**; which you need to compile and then you can replace the kernel image and modules on the target.

While the second link shows the **filesystem tree**; it means how the files and directories are organised  in the linux.

In some cases (**depend upon the type of flashed OS** ) you can see your kernel source code (*which you have mentioned in the first link*) in your running OS as well inside the `/usr/src/<kerne_path>` directory.